# how to write to new line in printer file?

Tags: rpgle

```
     A          R DETAIL
     A            STUNO          9S 0   5  3
     A            FIN            1A     5 19
     A                                  5 20'.'
     A            SLNAME        15A     5 22
     A            EXAM1          3S 0   5 42
     A            EXAM2          3S 0   5 48
     A            EXAM3          3S 0   5 54
     A            EXAM4          3S 0   5 61
     A            EXAM5          3S 0   5 66
     A            AVGSCORE       3S 0   5 72 SKIPB(1)
     A          R FOOTER
     A                                  6 56'Class Average'
     A            CLASSAVG       3S 0   6 72
```

This is my current printer file (header excluded) and my loop..

```
Write HEADER;
Read EXAMREC;
DOW Not %eof(wuexamp);
    EVAL(H) AVGSCORE = (EXAM1 + EXAM2 + EXAM3 + EXAM4 + EXAM5) / 5;
    Totalscore = Totalscore + AVGSCORE;
    FIN = SFNAME;
    RecordCount = RecordCount + 1;
    Write DETAIL;
    Read EXAMREC;
enddo;
    CLASSAVG = Totalscore / RecordCount;
    Write FOOTER;
```

I'm just learning RPG, what am I missing in my printer file to get it to print new details to a new line? The information I'm getting value wise while debugging seems to be correct through the loop but the only detail I have printed in my output is the last record that is read in.

Comment: I have rarely found any need to use external printer files.  Except output in the RPG program works well, with the advantage of keeping all the code in one source member.

Answer (score 1):

```
 A          R DETAIL                    SPACEA(1)
 A            STUNO          9S 0      3
 A            FIN            1A       19
 A                                    20'.'
 A            SLNAME        15A       22
 A            EXAM1          3S 0     42
 A            EXAM2          3S 0     48
 A            EXAM3          3S 0     54
 A            EXAM4          3S 0     61
 A            EXAM5          3S 0     66
 A            AVGSCORE       3S 0     72 
 A          R FOOTER                    SPACEA(1)
 A                                    56'Class Average'
 A            CLASSAVG       3S 0     72
```

Unlike a display file, the printer records are relative - they do not need to indicate the line number, only the position number in the line.